# A dynamic language on top of BEAM

Tags: programming-languages, beam

I have a question regarding the Erlang language.

I saw that people made the Elixir language on top of BEAM, and I was wondering, would it be possible to make a dynamic language like Python or Javascript on top of BEAM?

Can you recommend me some literature that would help me with this task, if it is possible in the first place?

Comment: that people have a name --- **Jose Valim** :)

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/llaisdy/beam_languages/. That page has a list of languages running on BEAM, as well as some resources about creating such languages.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement any dynamic language including Python or Javascript on top of BEAM but there is a catch. If your language requires mutable data structure it will be much more difficult and you will pay huge efficiency price. You will have to emulate it or heavily use NIFs with mutable data structures. It is part of the reason why there are new languages on top of BEAM instead of reimplemented existing ones. For example Elixir instead of Ruby. LFE instead of Lisp or Scheme.